# Recover the mutated source code (for robbers)

Tags: code-challenge, primes, cops-and-robbers, fibonacci, edit-distance

**This is the companion thread to the main [Recover the mutated source code (link)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42910/3808) challenge.** If you have successfully cracked a cop's answer, post your solution as an answer to this question.

As a reminder, here are the robber rules from the main challenge again:

> The robber will attempt to change the cop's program (which completes
>   Task #1) into a program that completes Task #2 (not necessarily the
>   original program written by the cop) in the edit distance specified by
>   the cop.
>
> An already-cracked submission cannot be cracked again (only the first
>   robber who cracks a submission gets credit).
>
> After cracking a submission, please do the following:
>
> - **Post an answer** to [this challenge's accompanying question (link)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42911/3808), providing the language, your solution, and a link to the original answer.
> - **Leave a comment** with the text "Cracked" that links to your posted answer.
> - **Edit the cop's answer** if you have edit privileges (if you do not, either wait until someone else with the required privileges does
>     so for you or suggest an edit).

And scoring:

> If a robber successfully cracks a cop's submission, the robber's score goes up by the edit distance of that submission. For example, a robber that cracks a submission with an edit distance of 3 and one with a distance of 5 earns 8 points. The robber with the highest score wins. In the event of a tie, the robber who earned the score first wins.

## Leaderboard

There are no cracked submissions yet.

Comment: Who is maintaining the leaderboard? And also, I think reader's score should go up more if the distance is less, since that would seem harder to me.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2, FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42917/)

```py
x=n=1;j=input();
while j>2:
    x,n=n,x+n;j-=1;
    ##while~-all(n%i for i in range(2,n)):n+=1;
print n
```

Used 12 edits. Put in an extra `#` to make it 13.

Comment: You need to use all 13 edits, but that can easily be fixed by adding another character in the comment.

Comment: Dammit, I forgot comments were a thing :/ Originally I changed the range to start at 1 and removed the ~ ;P

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman If you want no comments, you can change the range to be from `n` to `n`, so that the `all` evaluates to `True`. But `~-True` is `False`, so the while won't run.

Comment: I didn't "want" no comments, it just made this much easier than I thought it would be. Besides that, that is a much neater idea than what I came up with ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2, Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42922/30688)

```
from fractions import*
n=input()
k,=P=[1]
while n>len(P):k+=1;z=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,P[~1:]);P+=[z]#*(gcd(z,k)<2)
print P[-1]
```

Comment: On closer inspection, this is slightly different to the approach I originally had. Interesting...

Answer (score 3):

## [J, grc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42923/7311)

```
   f=:3 :'{.+/(!|.)i.y'

   f 45
1134903170
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3, Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42915/30688)

```
x=n= int(input())       # 3
P = [1,1]               #+2 = 5
k = 2
while n >=len(P):       #+1 = 6
 k += 1
 for x in P:
  if k%x ==~0: break    #+1 = 7
 else: P += [P[-2]+x]   #+7 = 14
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3, matsjoyce](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42952/30688)

```
a,c,n=1,1,int(input())
while n-1:
 #c+=1
 ##########list(map(c.__mod__,range(2,46))).count(0):
 a,c=a+c,a
 n-=1
print(c)
```

The Fibonacci program was strangely already in there...only needed 5 edits to get it.

Comment: Yeah, I designed it from the wrong end (and posted it, until Sp3000 spotted it), so it looks a little weird.

Answer (score 1):

## [JAGL, globby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42921/30630)

```
T~2]d]2C{cSdc+c]}wSP
```

It might not be the most efficient approach, it it is almost definitely not the Cop's code, but it works, and its 12 away.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam by Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42967/31414)

```
T1l~({_2$+}*p];
```

Takes input `n` from STDIN

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2, Pietu1998](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42959/30688)

```
f=lambda p,i:p if p[45:]else f(p+[i]#f all(i%q for q in p[1:])else
,p[-1]+i)
print f([1,1,1],2)[input('!')]
```

I used 9 edits to get a Fibonacci program.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I do have 12. See the pointless argument to `input`.

Comment: Well... I believe this would output the `!`. Still accepting this as valid, you could put any chars in the comment,

Comment: @Pietu1998 What's wrong with having a prompt on user input?

Comment: Nothing, but this is operationally different.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby, histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42957/21475)

```
p [x=1,y=1,*(1..200).map{|i|z=y;y+=(y*x**(i-1)+x%2).divmod(i)[2-1]?x:1;x=z;y}].-([x-1])[gets.to_i-1]
```