# Quine Anagrams! (Robbers' Thread)

Tags: code-golf, quine, cops-and-robbers, permutations

This is the robbers' thread. For the cops' thread, click [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99469/quine-anagrams-cops-thread).

#### Cops' Task

For the cops' thread, click [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99469/quine-anagrams-cops-thread).

#### Robbers' Task

- Find an uncracked submission on the cops' thread. (A submission may only be cracked once.)
- Unscramble the code to find a working quine.
- Post an answer on the robbers' thread. Include the language, the byte count, the user who posted the scrambled code, a link to that answer, and the unscrambled code.

Here is an example of a robber submission:

> ## Python, 29 bytes, [Oliver](http://localhost/i/cant/post/a/link/to/a/quote)
>
> ```
> _='_=%r;print _%%_';print _%_
> ```

#### Scoring

The user with the most cracks will be the winner of this section.

Comment: What is up with the link?!

Answer (score 6):

## Vim, 22 bytes, [Loojvo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99485/31716)

```
qtiqtqx0l"tp^V^[^[qx0l"tp
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=cXRpcXRxeDBsInRwFhsbcXgwbCJ0cA&input=)

Explanation:

```
qt                  " Start recording in register 'q'
  i                 " Enter insert mode
   qtqx0l"tp        " Enter this string
            ^V^[    " Enter a literal 'esc' character
                ^[  " Exit insert mode
                  q " Stop recording
```

At this point, the buffer looks like this:

```
qtqx0l"tp^[
```

And the cursor is on the last column (the 'esc' key).

```
x                   " Delete the esc character
 0l                 " Move to the second character on this line
   "tp              " And paste register 't'
```

Answer (score 6):

### [Underload](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 20 bytes, [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99541/8478)

```
(:a~*(*S)):a~*(*S)*S
```

[Try it online!](http://underload.tryitonline.net/#code=KDphfiooKlMpKTphfiooKlMpKlM&input=)

#### Explanation

The basic quine in Underload is this:

```
(:aSS):aSS
```

Here is how it works:

```
                                  Stack:               Output:
(:aSS)      # Push string.        (:aSS)
      :     # Duplicate.          (:aSS) (:aSS)
       a    # Wrap in (...).      (:aSS) ((:aSS))
        S   # Print.              (:aSS)               (:aSS)
         S  # Print.                                   (:aSS):aSS
```

The first issue was to reduce the number of `S` we need, because we've only got 3 for use here. We can do this by making use of swapping (`~`) and concatenation (`*`):

```
(:a~*S):a~*S
```

Here, instead of printing twice, we put the `(...)` version and the plain version of the string together and print that only once.

The bigger puzzle is how print an odd number of `*` and `S`. I'm not even sure how I actually arrived at the final solution, but it turns out that we can do this by putting the tail of the output in a separate string. That string itself is duplicated in the first string, but the contents are not, which gives us the extra occurrences of `*` and `S` we need. Here is a breakdown of the final solution:

```
                        Stack:                       Output:
(:a~*(*S))              (:a~*(*S))              
          :             (:a~*(*S)) (:a~*(*S))              
           a            (:a~*(*S)) ((:a~*(*S)))
            ~           ((:a~*(*S))) (:a~*(*S))
             *          ((:a~*(*S)):a~*(*S))
              (*S)      ((:a~*(*S)):a~*(*S)) (*S)
                  *     ((:a~*(*S)):a~*(*S)*S)
                   S                                 (:a~*(*S)):a~*(*S)*S
```

Answer (score 6):

### MATL, 20 bytes, [Luis Mendo](/a/99510/62101)

```
'wo&GzL0fk'tl#DwI-ch
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J3dvJkd6TDBmayd0bCNEd0ktY2g&input=)

I've never used MATL before, so my understanding may be slightly off, but this is basically how it works:

```
'wo&GzL0fk' This is a string representation of the code, offset by 3
t           Creates a duplicate copy of the string
l#D         Adds quotes to the second copy
w           Swap the unquoted version to the top of the stack
I-          Offset the characters in that version by 3
c           Convert back to characters
h           Join with the quoted string
```

Comment: Impressive! Especially considering this is your first Matlab answer. Well done!

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 54 bytes, [Loojvo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99481/38368)

```
l= ['l=', ';print l[0],`l`,l[1]'] ;print l[0],`l`,l[1]
```

Had a hard time finding it, as I have basically almost never touched python

Answer (score 4):

## Retina, 20 bytes, [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99905/34718)

```
\)1S*`\(?
\)1S*`\(?
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=ClwpMVMqYFwoPwpcKTFTKmBcKD8&input=)

I found this simply by messing around attempting to create a quine. I found the "shorter quine" that he hinted at first (or a similar one, at least), simply by experimenting (14 bytes):

```
\)1S*`
\)1S*`
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=ClwpMVMqYApcKTFTKmA&input=)

It took me about half an hour to an hour. Very clever, Martin!

Comment: Nice job! :) There are about 6 variants of the 14-byte quine, I think.

Comment: @MartinEnder I started by trying to shuffle your anagram around, but that wasn't helping, so I started with the known quine and modified that.

Comment: @MartinEnder Did you add the new quine to the "Golf you a quine" question?

Comment: [Yes.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67428/8478)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 49 bytes, [Mama Fun Roll](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99573/42545)

```
function f(){return    `${(((((k=>f+'')(f)))))}`}
```

Pretty much the standard JS function quine, with a little obfuscation.

Answer (score 3):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 36 bytes, [Erik the Golfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99655/8478)

```
'''000**rd3*:::?!;od0.!!+..233??dfrr
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=JycnMDAwKipyZDMqOjo6PyE7b2QwLiEhKy4uMjMzPz9kZnJy&input=)

I'm quite sure that this is not the intended solution. However, ><> quines make it fairly easy to get rid of most unwanted characters, except the `'`. Fortunately, the `:` made it quite easy to take care of those as well.

#### Explanation

```
'''                                    Push everything except these quotes onto the stack.
   000**                               In effect, pushes a zero.
        r                              Reverse the stack.
         d3*                           Push 39 (the quote character).
            ::                         Make two copies. The stack now holds
                                       a null-terminated representation of the
                                       entire code.
                                       The print loop begins here...
              :                        Duplicate top of stack.
               ?!;                     Terminate if zero.
                  o                    Otherwise, print.
                   d0.                 Jump back to position 13, i.e. the
                                       beginning of the print loop.
                      !!+..233??dfrr   Unused characters.
```

Comment: Yep, not the indended solution :P Well done.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 147 bytes, [jrich](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99589/42545)

`````````
+function e(){window[(w=[``>``]+``)[i=9/9]+w[i+i]+"ert"]('+'+e+'()');"  +./;;;;;=======>[]````````ccddddddeeeeeeeefiinnnnoooooorrrrrrrsttuwwx{}"}()
`````````

With all those extra chars, this is definitely not the intended solution :-)

Comment: Yep, definitely not the intended solution, but I'm impressed! Good job!

Comment: @jrich The trickiest part was figuring out how to balance the brackets and parens so that I wasn't using any extra ones. I see you didn't realize that the `(false+"")[1]` trick would be useful here? ;)

Comment: Didn't think about it to be honest... my solution was... a *little* more difficult to say the least

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 86 bytes, [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99551/34531)

```
y!r=r:y:r:[y]>>=id;main=putStr$[succ$'!']!"y!r=r:y:r:[y]>>=id;main=putStr$[succ$'!']!"
```

Nice idea to get the `"` via `succ$'!'` (ascii char after `!`). There were some missing chars to get them the usual way, i.e. implicitly via `show` or `print`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Befunge](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 15 bytes, [James Holderness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62101/james-holderness)

```
<:0:+1_@#%9,:g-
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=PDowOisxX0AjJTksOmct&input=)

#### Explanation

The catch here is that the loop terminates when the current character is divisible by 9, which is only the case for `-`. Hence, that needs to go at the end.

```
<                 Run code from right to left.
              -   There will always be 2 zeros on top of the stack at this
                  point, and this just reduces them to 1 zero.
             g    Get the character at the coordinates given by the top
                  two stack values, (0, 0) initially.
           ,:     Print a copy of that character.
         %9       Modulo 9.
      _@#         Terminate if that is 0.
    +1            Increment the x coordinate.
   :              Duplicate it.
 :0               Push two zeros.
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 110 bytes, [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99469/quine-anagrams-cops-thread/99476#99476)

```
<?php $x='<?php $x=0; echo strtr($x, array(chr(39).$x.chr(39)));'; echo strtr($x, array(chr(39).$x.chr(39)));
```

Thanks, I had fun and the `strtr([])` trick was a new one for me that I hope will save me some bytes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

### [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes, [Erik the Golfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99650/8478)

```
”ṘṘ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCd4bmY4bmY&input=)

There aren't really that many options... (Plus, this is the standard quine.)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 105 bytes, [Erik the Golfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99652/21487)

```py
a='a=%r;print a%%a ###(((())))**-01::@@@@@[[]]gggiiirrr~';print a%a ###(((())))**-01::@@@@@[[]]gggiiirrr~
```

It's just the standard Python string formatting quine...

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 53 bytes, [wat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100084/8478)

```
puts <<ENDIT*2,"ENDIT"
puts <<ENDIT*2,"ENDIT"
ENDIT
```

Just a modification of the standard heredoc quine:

```
puts <<2*2,2
puts <<2*2,2
2
```