# Anagram Quines (Robbers' Thread)

Tags: code-golf, quine, cops-and-robbers, permutations

*This is a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge the Cops' Thread can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/anagram-quines-cops-thread)*

Your challenge, as robbers is to take outputs from the cops' thread and find anagrams of the output that when run as a program output the original output provided.

The winner will be the person with the most valid cracks on this question.

### Rules

- You may not crack answers marked as safe with a provided program.
- If a cop provides a language that the intended solution is in you must crack it in that particular language, if they choose not to you may crack it in any competing language.
- Standard rules for Quines apply.
- Cracks must not be perfect Quines. i.e. they must not output their exact source but a reordering of it (the order is provided by the cop).

Comment: [CLosely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/99472/31716)

Answer (score 5):

## [Unspecified language (CJam), 254 bytes, DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111205/12012)

```
0000000: 3235 362c 583e 3130 2d5b 445d 2f41 612a  256,X>10-[D]/Aa*
0000010: 3a63 6523 0102 0304 0506 0708 090b 0c0e  :ce#............
0000020: 0f10 1112 1314 1516 1718 191a 1b1c 1d1e  ................
0000030: 1f20 2122 2425 2627 2829 2b2e 3334 3738  . !"$%&'()+.3478
0000040: 393b 3c3d 3f40 4243 4546 4748 494a 4b4c  9;<=?@BCEFGHIJKL
0000050: 4d4e 4f50 5152 5354 5556 5759 5a5c 5e5f  MNOPQRSTUVWYZ\^_
0000060: 6062 6466 6768 696a 6b6c 6d6e 6f70 7172  `bdfghijklmnopqr
0000070: 7374 7576 7778 797a 7b7c 7d7e 7f80 8182  stuvwxyz{|}~....
0000080: 8384 8586 8788 898a 8b8c 8d8e 8f90 9192  ................
0000090: 9394 9596 9798 999a 9b9c 9d9e 9fa0 a1a2  ................
00000a0: a3a4 a5a6 a7a8 a9aa abac adae afb0 b1b2  ................
00000b0: b3b4 b5b6 b7b8 b9ba bbbc bdbe bfc0 c1c2  ................
00000c0: c3c4 c5c6 c7c8 c9ca cbcc cdce cfd0 d1d2  ................
00000d0: d3d4 d5d6 d7d8 d9da dbdc ddde dfe0 e1e2  ................
00000e0: e3e4 e5e6 e7e8 e9ea ebec edee eff0 f1f2  ................
00000f0: f3f4 f5f6 f7f8 f9fa fbfc fdfe ff0a       ..............
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#ddNZdxU0EAfw936KPwpu2NvsCwJaXHBBQBEFZXG2FCpdvBasin71mvY@CJ5z522Sk9/JTCYndnx4sDzCje2b16/Y/uO7dzaOjxWbS1wF7dPOkvYWskt7G7v0grC5S0tsHRwebZ2ubcqB2hY/f/pMz/LF6e6rh/ASEzs5cau4hBhiRixBkFs0RB8dgmZGSlkRRvIoPhAQcnn/3lXvNn/65OHWNr23cQb4U4JKRMkhYqYBLroEl12Bq67Bdcdw4gy4JPbm4pVYEWESbngH732Ajz7BZ1/gq2/w3RM8e4FXP4nF/2JFxEn4EebNfQgIKWSEEipCCx2Bw6wrxoRYY5sEzr1x/sJbb7/z7sVFTLWtiHRaSI@MKFERR3JIIUWknApSTQ2pJ0LiJED/4PKVDz@69vGnn13//Isvv7qxIvIkkiZDGtkh@xyQY07IORfkmjsy5dlnywP4@uat2998e@e7u9//cP/HB48er4gyieJKQEmloNTSUHohFC6CosVQRnWovgbgZ9ax8@Tp7i/P9vYPDn9drog6iRprQs21oNbaUHslVK6CqtVQR3Novk3it6PnL34//uPPv17@/c9/7WyTaLEltNwKWm0NrTdC4yZo2gxtdIfue1j3In0SPfaEnntBr72h907o3AVdu6EPciBPawmaBEVKoEwFVKmBOhGISUBKBhrswJ7XEjwJjpzAmQu4cgN3JjCzgJUNPMRBvKwlZBISJUGyFEiVBulCEBaBqBhkqIN6XUvoJDRqgmYt0KoN2pWgrAJVNegwB/O2lrBJWLQEy1Zg1RqsG8HYBKZmsDEcxvwE64gxiTHnGiOPgjGHAGO@AcZsAca8AaYw//lZvA78Cw)

#### How it works

```
256,                Push the range [0 ... 255].
    X>              Remove the first item (0).
      10-           Remove 10 (0x0a).
         [D]/       Split at occurrences of 13 (0x0d).
             Aa*    Join, separating by 10 (0x0a).
                :c  Cast all integers to character.
                e#  Begins a comment, terminated by the linefeed at the very end.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), [Riley](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111204/56656)

```
()((((((()()()){}){}){})()){}{}){({}[()][((((((()()()()()){}){}){})()))]{})}{}((()()()){}()){({}[()][((((((()()()){}){}()){({}[()])}{})()()))]{})}{}((((()()()()){}){}()){}){({}[()][((((((((()()()()()){}){}){}())){}{})()()))]{})}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hqQEBmiCoWV0LRWA2iKlRXRutoRkbjawMQ6lmLJAGKkcyB0Rg0wvRhCQL0geRQTJFA9UaKI1mHjbXgIypxjDx////uo4A)

## Explanation

This was a bit easier than I had expected.

I wrote 3 separate loops to print each type of brace:

```
(((((()()()){}){}){})()){}{}){({}[()][((((((()()()()()){}){}){})()))]{})}{}
((()()()){}()){({}[()][((((((()()()){}){}()){({}[()])}{})()()))]{})}{}
((((()()()()){}){}()){}){({}[()][((((((((()()()()()){}){}){}())){}{})()()))]{})}{}
```

I used standard Mini-Flak technique to avoid using `<...>` monad and to be honest I never really felt the need to use the `<>` nilad.

This must have been extremely similar to what Riley did in the first place because when I was done I had an extra `()` left over. This is not a problem because `()` is essentially a no-op at the top level so I stuck it at the front of my program.

Comment: That's exactly what/how I wrote it. I needed the extra `()` to get everything to match up. Well done!

Answer (score 4):

### [Haskell, 107 bytes, Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111229/34531)

```
main=print$id=<<['|':[d]>>[d|i<-"$$'''',--..:<<<<====>>[[[[]]]]addddddiiiiiimnnprt|||",i==d]|d<-id['$'..]]
```

Plus a trailing newline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#HcmxCQAhDADAXURIow7wJC4iKYQ0KRQRy@zuB6@9O7pOWlvniSqE2MDga8K1NjHFHGIEl3Iu5UNHztOx6/LoM@Zc@5hZSEokbIJZpUGEUpjv/QE) (needs a few seconds to run, because it loops through all unicode characters).

The program has an `id` (right before `['$'..]`) which is not needed for the program logic, but somehow I have to spend the `i` and `d`.

Comment: The output is no in the same order.

Comment: @Laikoni: I misread the challenge. Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python, 96 bytes, Agargara](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/anagram-quines-cops-thread/111607#111607)

```py
f= 'B7ofx)wdr0o{1{6{{r){1x0sD00qF1{{24}wr2wlo)y))xm2'; print''.join([r+chr(ord(r)-9)for r in f])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#BcFBCsIwEAXQq8wuGaSSBGkp4kbES4grQzDFZvQrJDJ49vheTwcyx0lS4xrhRL2OqmD1zb1Pzr3OXjXsfhWhPoS/zG0NZk9P5PIxZrtILvaCze0OK4gWPMycBATKhdKVe/8D)

Once I noticed that some characters repeated in pairs, it was just a matter of finding a suitable ascii map between characters.

Comment: Congratulations! That's exactly how I wrote it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth, 32 bytes, Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/anagram-quines-cops-thread/111216#111216)

```
J+"J+J=JJ 1-2#pTN%"N #%2J=T-1pJJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@@@lreSl7WXr5aVgqGukXBDip6rkp6CsauRlG6JrWODl9f8/AA)

I don't really know Pyth that well, but I started with printing the required output and went from there.

```
 +"J+J=JJ 1-2#pTN%"N             # Add a '"' to the string in quotes
J                                # Assign result of above step to J
                     #           # Start an infinite loop
                      %2J=T-1    # Loops one iteration, then breaks
                                 # (I have no idea why this works)
                             pJ  # Explicitly print J
                               J # Implicitly print J
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam, 46 bytes, Business Cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/anagram-quines-cops-thread/111219#111219)

```
93]_:c58]99]95]93]e__:c36]95]95]101]101]e_$_:c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29pHBtvlWxqEWtpGWtpGgvkpsYDBYzNwDzTWEMDQzBOjVcBCv//DwA)

```
93]                                             # Push [93] onto the stack
   _                                            # Copy
    :c                                          # Push ascii char 93 ']'
      58 99 95 93                               # Push these numbers...
        ]  ]  ]  ]                              # Push entire stack as array
                  e__                           # Flatten and copy
                     :c                         # Map ascii values to all elements
                       36]95]95]101]101]        # Same as above
                                        e_      # Flatten
                                          $     # Sort
                                           _    # Copy, implicitly print
                                            :c  # Map ascii values to all elements
                                                # Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave, 91 bytes, drolex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/anagram-quines-cops-thread/111611#111611)

```
a=['111111111123666667eeegggkkknnszEEGn};:;:'];
disp(['a=[''',a,'''];',10,[a-10,']);']]);dd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@59oG61uCAdGxmYgYJ6ampqenp6dnZ2XV1zl6uqeV2ttZW2lHmvNlZJZXKARrQ7Spq6uk6gDJGOt1XUMDXSiE3WBpHqsprV6LJBISfn/HwA)

Very similar to the [python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111191/anagram-quines-robbers-thread/112046#112046) in that it abuses ascii values to print the characters it needs.

Comment: Cracked indeed. Well done.