# Golf an Anagram Quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, permutations

In [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/anagram-quines-cops-thread) I asked you to guess an anagram quine based on its output.  However it looks like we don't have a question asking to golf an anagram quine yet.  So your task will be to make the shortest anagram quine that you can.

#### What is an anagram quine?

An anagram quine is a non empty program that prints an anagram of its source code, other than its original source.

Here's an example of an anagram quine in Python 2:

```
print`'`print`*2'*2`
```

You should not read your own source for this challenge.

Comment: Does this have to be a proper quine?

Comment: @LeakyNun No, It *can't* be a quine.

Comment: Does the outputted code have to be a valid program?

Comment: Is code that doesn't actually meet our PPCG definition of a quine (minus the printing its source code) valid?

Comment: I could've sworn we had this exact challenge before, but I guess not...

Comment: @MDXF No it does not.

Comment: @Okx It should follow our standard requirements for a quine (other than it being a quine).

Comment: @LeakyNun Mind you, I don't think 0-byte programs have anagrams that differ from the original either!

Answer (score 31):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
)(
```

Outputs

```
()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1Pj/38A)

```
)  # Ends statement, does nothing in this program
 ( # Create an empty tuple
   # Implicitly print the empty tuple
```

Comment: Does that mean that you discovered that `()` is a quine much shorter than the [well known](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pyth) `jN*2]"jN*2]`?

Comment: @Jim no, because this isn't payload-capable :c

Answer (score 9):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

*Golfed 1 byte thanks to @WheatWizard by  using `!` and incrementing it to get `"`*

*Golfed 1 byte thanks to @ConorO'Brien by using `#` instead of `<!`*

```
":1->o#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nKUNcuX/n/fwA)

Outputs `"#o>-1:`.

#### Explanation

```
":1->o#"        Push this string (note that the IP wraps around)
:               Duplicate the top value of the stack (35 from the "#")
1-              Subtract one from it to get 34 ('"')
>o#             Print every character on the stack until the program cannot pop any more and still tries to pop a value from the stack afterwards
                The program exits with an error from not being able to pop a value from an empty stack
```

Comment: `":1+>o<!` is a bit shorter.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks, that was a neat golf :)

Comment: You can get 7 bytes: [`":1->o#`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nKUNcuX/n/fwA "><> – Try It Online")

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Thanks for the tip, that is really clever.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm pleasantly surprised that it works better here than in [the actual quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120991/31957)

Comment: Every forgets about the single quote, [`'d3*>o<`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xz3FWMsu3@b/fwA) :(

Answer (score 9):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 4 bytes

```
2ii2
```

Outputs:

```
i2i2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3ygz0@j/fwA)

Comment: 2x insert `i2`?

Comment: Yep. `2 -> do the next thing twice` `i -> insert the following`

Comment: Ah I see, I thought this was Vim.

Comment: @WheatWizard Nope, this is a trivial modification of the standard V quine.

Comment: This works in Vim too, right?

Comment: @isaacg: no, in Vim you'd need to press ESC once you were finished, which is a problem because there's no ESC character in the output.

Comment: @ais523 I see, I didn't realize Vim programs needed to leave insert mode.

Comment: @isaacg You have to press escape for the `2` part to take effect.

Answer (score 9):

## Brainfuck, 158 bytes

```
>>--<<-[[<+>->+>->+++<<<]>-]<<<<<<[--->>.<<]>>++<<<[->>>.<<<]>>-<<<[--->>>.<<<]>>>--<<<<[++>>>>.<<<<]>>>>+++>--.[---<.>]>+.......++.......<<<>>>>>>>>>-----+++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxRCoVQCEQXJOMKZDYi96OCIB68j6D1m1q3AcE5jrOey/Hfr@0XQQJmcDch2CNiZoMY1nIApBZinzxt@QL4ApN0X0IRvrBp1eZJK2zKQdFHMpcMcgql/Ii4AQ)

It may not be the shortest version, but at least it works.

*Fun fact*, the output code can actually be executed (and it does terminate).

### Output

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--------------------------++++++++++++++++++<....................[[[[[[[]]]]]]]
```

### Explanation

```
>>--<<-[[<+>->+>->+++<<<]>-]    Initializes the tape with the
                                help of a recurrence relation.
<<<<<<[--->>.<<]>>++<<<[->>>
.<<<]>>-<<<[--->>>.<<<]>>>--    Prints the characters using
<<<<[++>>>>.<<<<]>>>>+++>--.    classic loops.
[---<.>]>+.......++.......

<<<>>>>>>>>>-----+++            Junk to complete the anagram.
```

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, 32 bytes

```
print("""p"r"i"n"t"2(")*"""*2)
```

Prints `p"r"i"n"t"2(")*p"r"i"n"t"2(")*\n`, sorted output: `\n""""""""""""(())**22iinnpprrtt`

Comment: Oops, old version :(

Comment: @Downvoter Please undownvote.

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 8 bytes

```ruby
p"p*2"*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0CpQMtIScvo/38A)

This prints

```ruby
"p*2p*2"
```

### Explanation

This works similar to the python answer in the question.  It will make the string `p*2p*2` then using Ruby's `p` will print the representation of the string.

Comment: You can use `p` instead of `puts`?! So much wasted time...

Comment: @carusocomputing It's not precisely the same thing as puts. `p x` is equivalent to `puts x.inspect`

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>40</s> 32 bytes

```
f=($=`($)=>{$=$+"${"``"}$"}`)=>$+$
```

No messing around with Function.toString either. As a bonus, the code inside the string almost looks legal. Edit: Saved 8 bytes by using `+` instead of `repeat(2)`.

Comment: Why not use `*2` instead of `.repeat(2)`, does that not work?

Comment: @carusocomputing JavaScript does not overload `*` for strings

Comment: @carusocomputing That gave me an idea, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein), 7 + 6 = 13 bytes

Here's an answer based on the [><> answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125056/56656).

```
":1+@!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/1/JylDbQZHr////BgYG/3UdAQ)

This outputs

```
:1+@!"
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Found a better way :-)

```
Q+2ç"Q+2ç
```

Outputs `"Q+2çQ+2ç`. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=USsy5yJRKzLn&input=)

#### Explanation

```
Q+2ç"Q+2ç    // Implicit: Q = quotation mark
    "Q+2ç    // Take this string.     Q+2ç
  2ç         // Repeat it twice.      Q+2çQ+2ç
Q+           // Prepend a quote.      "Q+2çQ+2ç
             // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Could also be `Qi2ç"Qi2ç`, which prints `Qi2çQi2ç"`. This one is closer to the standard Japt quine:

```
"iQ ²"iQ ²
```

But I do not believe there is any easy way to wedge the quotation mark in the middle of the string for a 9-byte quine.

Comment: Another 10-byter: `Q+"+Q² " ²`

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Yep, and you can always arrange the 4 chars inside the string in each of the 24 possible permutations. Also I believe you can always replace both spaces with newlines

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 20 bytes

```ruby
$><<%q($><<%q()*2)*2
```

This outputs

```
$><<%q()*2$><<%q()*2
```

Taking advantage of Ruby's `%q(...)` string syntax, which supports nested parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 8 bytes

```
_

$nn$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fK56LSyUvT@X/fwA)

Prints

```
n$_
n$
```

Both contain one `_`, two `n`, two `$` and three linefeeds.

Note that a linefeed followed by almost any other character is a trivial solution, but it's questionable whether it's valid, because the second character only encodes itself and the linefeed doesn't really encode either output character.

### Explanation

```
_
```

Replace the empty input with a `_`.

```
$nn$
```

Match an empty string, which happens both before or after the `_` and insert a linefeed (`$n`), an `n`, and a `$`. Since we first inserted that `_`, this adds each of those characters twice, so the `n` and `$` account for the `$n`, and we get two of the three linefeeds we need in the output. The third linefeed is printed because Retina prints a trailing linefeed by default.

We could also use `n$n$` in this stage, which would then print:

```
n
$_n
$
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python Repl, 4 bytes

This is my first Code Golf solution, so I hope it meets the rules. In the Python 2 or 3 interactive interpreter:

```
>>> (1),
(1,)
```

The output is an anagram of the input.

---

Another:

```
>>> 2*'2*'
'2*2*'
```

In Python 2:

```
>>> type('rst <>'),
(<type 'str'>,)
```

In Python 3:

```
>> {1, 0}
{0, 1}
```

Update 2017-06-15: Yet another:

```
>>> 01.
1.0
```

Comment: I think the last answer here violates the quine rules (all the characters in the output serve the same purpose as the matching character in the input). The others are fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>38</s> 39 bytes

```hs
main=print$[0,0]>>"main=print$[0,0]>>"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0Ql2kDHINbOTgmLENf//wA) Output:

```hs
"main=print$[0,0]>>main=print$[0,0]>>"
```

Edit: +1 byte because I previously forgot about the implicit trailing newline of `print`.

---

**Alternative:** (Same byte count but does not contain ASCII-owl)

```hs
main=print$e++e;e="main=print$e++e;e="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0QlVVs71TrVVgmLENf//wA)

Output:

```hs
"main=print$e++e;e=main=print$e++e;e="
```

Comment: Just barely an anagram quine rather than a true quine....

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
'∞∞''∞'JJ∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f/VHHPCBSB9HqXl5A8v9/AA)

## Output:

```
∞∞''JJ''∞∞
```

---

## Explanation:

```
Code       | Explanation                | Stack
-----------+----------------------------+-------------------
'∞         | Push literal '∞'.          | ["∞"]
  ∞        | Mirror.                    | ["∞∞"]
   ''      | Push literal "'".          | ["∞∞","'"]
     ∞     | Mirror.                    | ["∞∞","''"]
      'J   | Push literal 'J'.          | ["∞∞","''","J"]
        J  | Join it all together.      | ["∞∞''J"]
         ∞ | Mirror.                    | ["∞∞''JJ''∞∞"]
-----------+----------------------------+-------------------
           | Implicit print.            | ∞∞''JJ''∞∞
```

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, <s>24</s> 20 bytes

```
{"""{""*""2""}"""*2}
```

*-4 thanks to CalculatorFeline, the whitespace wasn't needed after all!*

## Output:

```
{""*""2""}{""*""2""}
```

## Explanation:

Anonymous closure that, when called, returns `{""*""2""}` two times (concatenated).

Comment: Explanation please. Also, bytes can (probably) be saved by using the `*2` as padding between quotes: `{"""{""*""2""}"""*2}`

Comment: @CalculatorFeline it's pretty self explanatory. But yes, that is a <s>100%</s> 9% better idea than mine.

Comment: Actually, it's only 9% better :P

Answer (score 2):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
"_`"_`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Xyk@AYj@/wcA)

Prints

```
_`"_`"
```

#### Explanation

```
"_`"   e# Push this string.
_      e# Duplicate.
`      e# Stringify it, which wraps it in quotes.
       e# Implicitly print stack contents.
```

Comment: I was about to post this... "\`_"_\` also works

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 44 bytes

```php
<?=str_repeat('<?=\str_\repeat(\'\',2);',2);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKQovii1IDWxREMdyI0B8WOgAjHqMeo6RprWYOL//695@brJickZqQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fission 2](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), <s>9 8</s> 6 bytes

```
R"'!+O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8ssLs7MzzP6/z9ISV1R2///fwA)

## Explanation

An atom is created at `R`, which moves right. This atom then comes across a `"`, which starts printing mode. In printing mode, all characters (until the matching `"`) are printed. This means it prints `'!+OR` in this case. Then, all that is left is printing `"`, which is done by the remaining characters. `'!` sets the atom's mass to the character code of `!`, and `+` increments it to the character code of `"`. Then, the character code is output by `O` and the atom is destroyed, ending the program.

(Actually, this is just a rotation of the shortest quine)

Comment: I believe you can just use the standard quine and shift it cyclically (so something like `R"'!+O`, untested).

Comment: @MartinEnder: you're right. Updated. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

### Bash, 36 bytes

```sh
tee f<<<'tee f<<<""cat f'"''"
cat f
```

This outputs

```sh
tee f<<<""cat f''
tee f<<<""cat f''
```

(and creates the file `f` as a side effect, but that's allowed [per meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8871/3808).)

Both the program and output have a trailing newline.

Thought process: I figured that the easiest way to output a string two times, aside from assigning it to a variable, was to do

```sh
tee f<<<string
cat f
```

The string needs to be quoted because it will contain spaces and `<` characters, so then I had

```sh
tee f<<<'tee f<<<cat f'
cat f
```

which almost works, except it doesn't output the quotes. Fortunately, Bash supports string literal concatenation by simply placing them next to each other, so appending `"''"` to the herestring and inserting `""` inside the single quote part yields this solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 11 bytes

```
' 2+">:#,_@
```

Prints:

```
+2 '@_,#:>"
```

Explanation:

```
' 2+"        Put a " on the stack (32 + 2)
    "        Put the rest of the code on stack (wrap-around string)
     >:#,_   Print stack
          @  End
```

Comment: Yes. but so does `"`.  What is the restriction on that exactly?

Comment: I don't think that `"` is considered reading ones own source, its just a string literal. `g` however is pretty blatantly reading its own source.

Comment: @WheatWizard okay. I will change it.

Comment: `":1+>:#,_@!` also works but its not shorter.

Comment: `' 2+"8k,@` for 9 bytes

Comment: `"` in Befunge forms a "topological quine" (in which the program is inside and outside a string literal at the same time). The written version of our rules is really unclear on whether that counts as reading your own source or not, but we've historically allowed it.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
"2*`"2*`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X8lIKwGE//8HAA)

#### Explanation

Similar to the Python example in the question

```
"2*`"     e# Push the string "2*`"
     2*   e# Repeat it twice
       `  e# Get its string representation (wrap in quotes)
```

The output is `` "2*`2*`" ``.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 8 bytes

```
?A+@?A@+
```

I [just figured out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125089/44874) how to do a proper quine in QBIC. Making an anagram out of it is done by simply switching around the characters in the string literal. There are 24 possible anagrams this way.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 8 bytes

```
"'$<@,k7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X0ldxcZBJ9v8/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 14 bytes

```
"æ3M.Cæ"æ3M."C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f9f6fAyY18958PLIAwl5///AQ)

Output:

```
æ3M.CæC.M3æ"""
```

#### Explanation

```
"æ3M.Cæ"æ3M."C
"æ3M.Cæ"       # Pushes "æ3M.Cæ"
        æ      # Palindrone of that string
         3M    # 3 times...
           ."   # Push " on the stack
             C  # Concatenate with the string above
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 15 bytes

```
f=(s='f=')=>f+s
```

**Outputs:**

```
(s='f=')=>f+sf=
```

**Snippet:**

```js
f=(s='f=')=>f+s

console.log(f());
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 2 bytes

```
.0
```

Output:

```
0.
```

A number starting with a decimal point such as `.123` is interpreted as `0.123`, so `.0` is interpreted as `0.0`. Since the part of the number after the decimal point is zero, Mathematica does not print it.

Comment: I don't think this is valid.  Our site definition requires that quines have an "encoder" and a "decoder", this bans literal only type quines.

Comment: All the rules for quines carry over to this challenge.

Comment: @WheatWizard: The `.` encodes itself, but I don't think the `0` does? A 0 beyond the decimal point can't sanely be seen as encoding a leading zero before the decimal point, the latter's a side effect of printing a float. So under the old quine rules, there's no problem here. (I'm not sure whether the new rules have come into force yet.)

Comment: @ais523 I don't know.  Perhaps this should be addressed by a meta question.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (yet another one), 11 bytes

```
f=_=>'=f'+f
```

Called with `f()`, outputs

```
=f_=>'=f'+f
```

```js
f=_=>'=f'+f

console.log(f());
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3, 31 bytes

```
a='a=%r;pritn(a%%a)';print(a%a)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>8</s> 4 bytes

```
.S.S
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=.S.S&i=&a=1)

A direct port of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/156643#156643).

Old version, 8 bytes

```
..b..LbL
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=..b..LbL&a=1)

Alternative version with a pretty cheap trick that can be applied to proper quines in almost any language.

```
"43bL"34bL
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%2243bL%2234bL&a=1)

Because `"34bL"34bL` is a proper quine in Stax.

Yet another version, using only single-char string literals.

```
''c'Lc'cccLcLL
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%27%27c%27Lc%27cccLcLL&i=&a=1)

### Explanation

```
.S.S        Generates powerset ["","S","S.","."]
            Implicit flatten and output

..b         Push string ".b"
   ..L      Push string ".L"
      b     Duplicate both strings
       L    Concatenate all 4 strings to a single one.
```

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 2 bytes

```
1-
```

### Explanation

```
a   % (Implicit) argument of the input
    % The input is automatically set to 0
    % if it isn't specified
 1- % Minus 1 over the input (i.e. 0-1 = -1)
```

Output:

```
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 8 bytes

```
`.,:`:,.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/QU/HKsFKR@//fwA)

A rearrangement of the usual quine.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
"34çJ∞"34çJ∞
```

Outputs:

```
34çJ∞""∞Jç43
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fydjk8HKvRx3z4Ayu//8B)

```
"34çJ∞"      # Push this string                 | [ 34çJ∞ ]
       34ç   # Push a quote (")                 | [ 34çJ∞, " ]
          J  # Join                             | [ 34çJ∞" ]
           ∞ # Mirror                           | [ 34çJ∞""∞Jç43 ]
             # Implicitly output with a newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 60 bytes

```
main(s){printf(s="main(s){s=printf(%c%s%1$c,34,s);}",34,s);}
```

Just [the shortest C quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122856/61563) with trivial modifications.

Output:

```
main(s){s=printf("main(s){s=printf(%c%s%1$c,34,s);}",34,s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPo1izuqAoM68kTaPYVgkmUmwLFVNNVi1WNVRJ1jE20SnWtK5VgjH@/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [shortC](https://github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 34 bytes

```
Bs){Rs="Bs){s=R%c%s%1$c,34,s",34,s
```

Output:

```
Bs){s=R"Bs){s=R%c%s%1$c,34,s",34,s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fqVizOqjYVglEF9sGqSarFqsaqiTrGJvoFCuByf//AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [str](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/str), 10 bytes

```
`2xr;`2xr;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4p@v8/waiiyBpM/P8PAA) Outputs `` `2xr;2xr;` ``

```
`2xr;`2xr;
.........;   preamble
`2xr;`       a string containing those character
      2x     repeat twice
        r    print the representation of that doubled string
         ;   end preamble (no program)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
“ØvṚ”Ṙv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9qZWxsef//4oCcw5h24bma4oCd4bmYdv//)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
"V#!1+!@@R!&@&@;"V#!1+!@@R!&@&@;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fKUxZ0VBb0cEhSFHNQc3BGp3//z8A)

Outputs `""V#!1+!@@R!&@&@;V#!1+!@@R!&@&@;`, which is the source, but with both `"` at the start, the `;` is required at the end to prevent a trailing newline

### Explanation:

```
"V#!1+!@@R!&@&@;"V#!1+!@@R!&@&@;  
"V#!1+!@@R!&@&@;"                 Pushes the charcode of each char in the string
                 V                Create stack2 and switch to it
                  #!              Push charcode of !
                    1+            Increment to charcode of "
                      !@@         Print twice, popping the 2nd time
                         R        Return to stack1
                          !&@&@   Print entire stack twice, popping the 2nd time
                               ;  Suppress implicit output to prevent trailing newline
```

Alternatively (not sure this one actually meets the requirement of it being a proper quine):

### [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 2 bytes

```
1
```

`\n1`, outputs `1\n`

### Explanation:

```
\n1
\n   No-op, does nothing
  1  Pushes 1
     Implicit output of last item on stack plus trailing newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 88 bytes

```java
v->{String s="-v>{String s=%c%s%1$c;return s.format(s,34,s);}";return s.format(s,34,s);}
```

Outputs with both `v` and `-` swapped as anagram:

```java
-v>{String s="-v>{String s=%c%s%1$c;return s.format(s,34,s);}";return s.format(s,34,s);}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dY6xCoMwEIb3PsUhFRJQobRbsG9Ql0KX0iGNscRqlNwZKOKz24gOXQp3w3//wffV0su067Wty/esGokIF2nsuAMwlrSrpNJQLBHgSs7YFyh260wJnotwncKGQZJkFBRgIYfZp@dxe8Y8Sv1PilWM8WGvhNM0OAuYVZ1rJTFMjqcEuZii/9UsVlo/PJtA26B@sWmDNFsp94fkm/AHSbdZN1DWh4aYzRSzQ9PwzX2avw)

- The `String s` contains the unformatted source code (with `-` and `v` swapped to make it an anagram.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together.

Answer (score 0):

## Microscript II, 8 bytes

```
"phq"pqh
```

## Microscript, 11 bytes (also a reverse quine):

```
0"Caxq"Caxq
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
00,”ṘṘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/AQOdRw9yHO2cA0f//AA)

Output is

```
0,”Ṙ0Ṙ
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 8 bytes

```
{}*{.*}.
```

Output is `{.*}{.*}`

Works because the first three characters are garbage to find a way to get another set of braces in the program that don't show up.

If you don't care about whitespace, then `{+}{.}+.` outputs `{+ .}{+ .}`, which was my first attempt.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v7pWq1pPq1bv/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 38 bytes

```
=REPT("=REPT(CHAR(34),2)&"&CHAR(34),2)
```

Output is:

```
=REPT(CHAR(34),2)&"=REPT(CHAR(34),2)&"
```

If you sort and concatenate the characters from either, you get this:

```
""&&(((()))),,==223344AACCEEHHPPRRRRTT
```